# Can Google Play Privacy Policy URL be written in pastebin

Tags: google-play, privacy-policy

I am trying to upload an app to the Google Play store but am failing to find a way to upload a privacy policy url.
I have tried generators and they are all cost money or have flaws.
My question is can a privacy policy url be a pastebin link?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly **yes** -- you can host the Privacy Policy anywhere you wish as long as the page is **public** and you have control over the contents of the pages (i.e. to update the Privacy Policy).

Your other alternatives to host the Privacy Policy for a Google Play Store app:

- [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)
- [Medium blog](https://medium.com)
- [Blogger.com](https://blogger.com)

The tool we're developing - TermsFeed - might help you: you can create and host your Privacy Policy (and link to it).